# Difference between poll_disconnected, poll_in, poll_out and cancellations

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, posix

I am debugging [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) python application

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    threadpool = reactor.getThreadPool()
```

And seeing that:

```
_POLL_DISCONNECTED = 24 
_POLL_IN = 1
_POLL_OUT = 22
_cancellations = 100
```

What does this constants or parameters mean? Does they come from POSIX? What does cancellations mean?